# Using a Single-String Regex While Doing In-Place Perl Editing

Tags: regex, perl, command-line

I'm using one-off `perl -pi -e` commands to do simple search and replace from within a bash script. Most of my regexes work fine, until I get to these:

```
perl -pi -e 's#\<\?mso-application.*\<Table.*Rows="1"\>#\<Table\>#s' 1.xml
perl -pi -e 's#\</Table.*#\</Table\>#s' 1.xml
```

Please don't mind the # marks instead of slashes, I didn't want to escape even more characters. These regexes are supposed to essentially delete chunks of an XML file exported from excel, but aren't working. This seems to be because I'm using logic that applies to strings, and trying to apply it to a file (though I admit I have only a basic understanding of perl's in-place editing).

Is there an alternative way to do this (whether in perl, awk, or sed) that can be issued from within a shell script?

Comment: Can you show the smallest example file and point out what you are trying to fix and in what way it is not a valid XML file?

Comment: Ultimately, I got my regexes working by calling a perl helper script from the bash script, but I do appreciate your help. And the smallest example file is half a megabyte, and trust me, it's UGLY.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend that you give up the notion of editing XML files on the command line using regexes and use a proper XML parser instead.

Comment: Understood, and generally I would, but the circumstances of this situation make it necessary, unfortunately.

Comment: @Ether: In that I have to take the output of a tool that doesn't actually generate valid XML (that I had nothing to do with, btw) and make it valid. It's pretty much been decided that nobody's going to bother fixing the tool. And seeing as it's not valid, I can hardly parse it.

Comment: @Interwebs: ugh, I feel your pain. Any chance that you can stop using this broken tool and switch to something functional going forward?

Answer (score 4):

You have perl setup in line processing mode, but chances are the patterns you are trying to match span multiple lines.  You will need to expand your perl scripts to read in the entire file, and then run the regexes against the entire file.

Answer (score 3):

From the command line, add the [-0777](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-0*[_octal/hexadecimal_]) flag to make perl read the entire file (and make sure you have the /s regex flag to make . match newlines, which you do).  So:

```
perl -pi -0777 -e 's#\<\?mso-application.*\<Table.*Rows="1"\>#\<Table\>#s' 1.xml
perl -pi -0777 -e 's#\</Table.*#\</Table\>#s' 1.xml
```

Comment: Adding `/g` will also be needed if the pattern can appear more than once in a file.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things:

- Avoid using regexes to manipulate XML files because there are better tools for the job. Consider the [`XML::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/~grantm/XML-Simple-2.18/lib/XML/Simple.pm) or [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Twig/) modules to achieve the same need.
- Seeing that you have multiple search-and-replace operations, replace the one-liners with a proper Perl script and call that from your Bash script instead.